# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column when column exist active admin registering a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Updated

I just notice that my collections table actually does not have a user_id in it. I just added it.

```
  create_table "collections", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "collectable_id"
    t.string   "collectable_type"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "team"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

but its still throwing me an error.

Updated with controllers

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    if params[:user_id]
      @collections = User.find(params[:user_id]).collections
    elsif params[:pic_id]
      @pic = Pic.find(params[:pic_id])
      @collections = current_user.collections
      render partial: 'modal', layout: false
    else
      @collections = current_user.collections
    end
  end

  def edit
    @collection = Collection.find params[:id]
  end

  def update
    @collection = Collection.find params[:id]

    if @collection.update_attributes(collection_params)
      redirect_to collections_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def create
    @collection = Collection.new(collection_params)
    @collection.collectable = current_user

    if @collection.save
      @pic = @collection.pics.first
      @collections = current_user.collections
      render partial: 'modal', layout: false
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])

    if current_user.collections.include? @collection or current_user.admin?
      @collection.destroy
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'You do not have permission to delete this inspiration collection'
    end
    redirect_to collections_path
  end

  def show
    @collection = Collection.find params[:id]
    @brand = Brand.find(params[:from_brand_id]) if params[:from_brand_id]
  end

  def remove_pic
    @collection = Collection.find params[:id]

    if @collection.collectable_type == 'User' and current_user.id == @collection.collectable_id
      @collection.pic_relationships.where(pic_id: params[:pic_id]).each{|pic_relationship| pic_relationship.destroy}
    end

    @pic = Pic.find params[:pic_id]
    @collections = current_user.collections
    render partial: 'collections/modal', layout: false
  end

  private

  def collection_params
    params.require(:collection).permit(:title, pic_relationships_attributes: [:id, :pic_id, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

--

I am registering the collection model with active admin. I just did this

```
rails generate active_admin:resource collection
```

I am using rails 4 so I have permitted params inside my app/admin/collection model

```
ActiveAdmin.register Collection do

  permit_params :collectable_id, :collectable_type, :title, :description, :created_at, :updated_at, :team


  # See permitted parameters documentation:
  # https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
  #
  # permit_params :list, :of, :attributes, :on, :model
  #
  # or
  #
  # permit_params do
  #   permitted = [:permitted, :attributes]
  #   permitted << :other if resource.something?
  #   permitted
  # end
end
```

Here is my collections table

```
  create_table "collections", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "collectable_id"
    t.string   "collectable_type"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "team"
  end
```

when I head to my admin panel and click on edit under a record

I am getting this

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /admin/collections/3/edit
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'collections.collectable_type' in 'where clause': SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 AND (`collections`.`collectable_type` = 'User')  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

The collectable type's value is user and I can see it in the admin dashboard when I click view. The data exist so why is it saying that the column is missing?

Comment: Post your collections controller

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks like the following

```
SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 AND (`collections`.`collectable_type` = 'User')  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

If you look at the query carefully, you are selecting from users table. users table doesn't know about collections.collectable_type.

you query should join collections with users

```
SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` join collections on collections.collectable_id = users.id WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 AND (`collections`.`collectable_type` = 'User')  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I don't have a controller in active admin. I am registering the collection model/table only. I am not sure why its running the sql queries through the user table.